# Jersey should not consume any form parameter. exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I am building rest webservice using jersey, when I add this function i got this exception, but when i remove it, the server works very good.

```
Customer.orderWeb(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), should not consume any form parameter.
```

the code is

```
@Path("orderWeb/{customerID}/{restaurantID}/{IDs}/{numbers}/{descriptions}/{addressID}")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN,
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN,
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public String orderWeb(@FormParam("customerID") String customerID,
            @FormParam("restaurantID") String restaurantID,
            @FormParam("IDs") String IDs, @FormParam("numbers") String numbers,
            @FormParam("descriptions") String descriptions,
            @FormParam("addressID") String customerAddress) {
        return "WSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS";
    }
```

it is weird because I always use path like that path. i dont know what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using @FormParam. Also make sure INPUT HTML types are using name= not id=.

Comment: I found the solution , it was "formpath" not "formparm", i will accept ur answer

Comment: wait please, do u mean that I can receive request from html form ?

Comment: please how could I do that? I need it very much

Comment: i mean if you are usinig any HTML form then INPUt tag should have name attribute rather than id

Comment: so that function can be used directly from php or html when I put name for my form , right?

Comment: u said , see this, what this?

Comment: in ur second answer , which u just deleted  :P

Comment: posted by mistake sorry for that

Answer (score 22):

Use `@QueryParam` with `@GET` and `@FormParam` with `@POST`

Comment: your answer is perfect in my case

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you got fixed from the approved answer, but since I'm not seeing the answer FYI you should use @PathParam to capture path segments (not @FormParam which is to capture POST data)